# AppEngine use-google-connector-j in YAML

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**Bug report:** https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11444

---

For Java projects, web.xml and appengine-web.xml can be replaced by a single app.yaml file. However, I'm having trouble with the `use-google-connector-j` property.

Here is the current state of my app.yaml...

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: java
threadsafe: true
system_properties:
  java.util.logging.config.file: WEB-INF/logging.properties

handlers: ...

use-google-connector-j: true
```

I keep getting the following error: `Unable to find property 'use-google-connector-j' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppYaml`

Comment: Could you solve this? I am getting [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class \[com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644148/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdb) and it could be that I'm just missing that `use-google-connector-j` property but how do I have to set it in my **app.yaml** file?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, app.yaml acts as a template to automatically generate web.xml and appengine-web.xml. I got around this error by renaming it to "app.yaml.backup" and adding the needed line to appengine-web.xml. If/when I need to make changes, I will change back app.yaml to its actual name, make my changes, deply (to generate the xml files), then repeat the process.

Answer (score -1):

Add:

> system_properties:

Above the property [as per here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_System_properties_environment_variables_and_context_parameters)

Comment: This actually doesn't work. The `use-google-connector-j` property should be an entity on it's own but it doesn't seem like it's valid.

Comment: You are correct, looks like it might be a bug. I'd open a Bug Report on their PIT https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: I have `system_properties: use-google-connector-j: true` but it's not working - getting "unexpected attribute 'system_properties' for object of.." Can you please update your answer to a working example?