# Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;'

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I can't seem to get this to work ..

I am using **Google Flexible Environment** and want to connect to my **Second Generation Cloud SQL** database. I am currently getting this exception:

```
[main] ERROR com.mahlzeit.server.BootstrappingServerConfig - Error trying to migrate SQL scripts ..
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1385)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;' due to underlying exception:
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/SocketFactory;
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3321)
    ...
```

This is how I am configuring my `DataSource`:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://google/mz_db?cloudSqlInstance=mz-test:us-central1:mz-life-cloudsql-prod&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

I have added the [`mysql-socket-factory`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory) as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

so why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Is this your configuration on the local machine or in production? I'm having problem with flexible env to SQL cloud connection in production. Which is your Driver classname?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end so it's trying to load a class called `com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;` Try removing the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Yep, it was the `&` to `&amp;` issue and then remove the `;` which was what Eclipse suggested as I used just `&`. If "`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker`" rings a bell please let me know ^^