# SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 - Communicationslinkfailure between Appengine Standard -> Google SQL managed instance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, spring-data-jpa

Could see following errors when connecting to GCP- Mysql instance .

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Communications link failure
```

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

Following are done as part of preliminary steps

Set both

```
wait_timeout
2147483
interactive_timeout
2147483
```

Configuratiion

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" /> 
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://sqlinstanceConnectionstring" /> 
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="Select 1" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="30" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
</bean>
```

any help appreciate

Comment: Where are you connecting from (external application, app engine...)? Keep in mind that the `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` is designed for App Engine Standard environment. You can also check this other thread where the same issue is discussed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644148/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdb

Comment: As mentioned above connecting from App engine to google mysql sql instance. I could see SQL state 8s01 and connection Communications link failure

Comment: App Engine Standard or Flexible?

Comment: App Engine  Standard only

Comment: Could you share a snipet of how the configuration is structured in the code?